# django form.is_valid returns false

Tags: python, html, django, view, orm

When ever I submit my form and check the form is not getting submited and is redirected. The validation is always false. I entered all the fileds and it still shows the same. Why is this keep showing like this? is there something wrong? Below are the files i use views,template, and forms.

**views.py**

```
def signincheck(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        formsignin = FormSignup(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if formsignin.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse("Password not match 3")
            TbluserVar=Tbluser()
            TbluserVar.firstname=formsignin.cleaned_data['firstname']
            TbluserVar.lastname=formsignin.cleaned_data['lastname']
            TbluserVar.username=formsignin.cleaned_data['username']
            Password=formsignin.cleaned_data['password']
            ConfirmPassword=formsignin.cleaned_data['confirm_password']
            TbluserVar.mobilenumber=formsignin.cleaned_data['mobilenumber']
            Tbluser.dateofbirth=formsignin.cleaned_data['dob']
            Tbluser.dateofjoining=datetime.datetime.today()
            Tbluser.userlevel=0
            if Password != ConfirmPassword:
                messages.error(request,'Password and Confirm Password does not match')
                return redirect('/')

            else:
                try:
                    user = Tbluser.objects.get(username=formsignin.cleaned_data['username'])
                    messages.error(request,'Username not available. Try another one.')
                    return redirect('/')

                except:
                    PasswordEnc=hashlib.md5(Password.encode())
                    RealPassword=PasswordEnc.hexdigest()
                    TbluserVar.passwordenc=RealPassword
                    TbluserVar.save()
                    request.session['username']=TbluserVar.username
                    request.session['getFirstandLastName']=TbluserVar.firstname + " " + TbluserVar.lastname
                    FullName=request.session['getFirstandLastName']
                    return redirect('/index')

        else:
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        return HttpResponse("NOT CORRECT")
```

**forms.py**

```
class FormSignup(forms.Form):
    firstname=forms.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name...','class':'loginform'}))

    lastname=forms.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name...','class':'loginform'}))

    username=forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'User Name...','class':'loginform'}))
    password=forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password...','class':'loginform'}))
    confirm_password=forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Password...','class':'loginform'}))
    mobilenumber=forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Mobile Number...','class':'loginform'}))
    dob=date = forms.DateTimeField(
        input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'],
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
        {
            'class':'datepicker',
            'placeholder': 'Date of Birth...'

        }))
```

**template.html**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalSignUpForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Sign in</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <form id="idlognform" method="POST" action="{% url 'signupcheck' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                  <div class="md-form mb-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
                    {{FormSignup1.firstname}}
                  </div>

                  <div class="md-form mb-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
                    {{FormSignup1.lastname}}
                  </div>

                  <div class="md-form mb-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
                    {{FormSignup1.username}}
                  </div>

                  <div class="md-form mb-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
                    {{FormSignup1.password}}
                  </div>

                  <div class="md-form mb-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
                    {{FormSignup1.confirm_password}}
                  </div>

                  <div class="md-form mb-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
                    {{FormSignup1.mobilenumber}}
                  </div>

                  <div class="md-form mb-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
                    {{FormSignup1.dob}}
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                      <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="signinbutton" value="Login">
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{form.errors}}
              </form>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You should not handle invalid forms by redirecting. You should just re-render the bound form in the same template, showing the errors. Look at [the example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view). In your template, make sure you also show the errors (e.g. `{{FormSignup1.confirm_password.errors}}`) below each field or just `{{form.errors}}` at the top to list all errors.

Comment: Also you should handle validation in your form, not in your view, so you can just add errors to the form errors by raising `ValidationError`. Again, look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/). Finally, **don't save passwords like you are doing**, it's totally insecure. Django provides you with secure password hashing mechanisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because in the forms.py you are using `dob=date=`. It doesnt look like a valid django form. Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. It was my miskate though.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try your code later. Anyway just reading  you could try this:
in views.py to put in the else of if formsignin.is_valid():

```
formsignin = FormSignup()
```

but maybe the above behavior is not what you want.
And especially  in form.py put:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FormSignup, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```